# Rectangle-Rectangle Intersection Area - Area Only

Tags: algorithms, area, computational-geometry

Suppose I have two rectangles that are not necessarily axis-aligned. What is a fast way to calculate their intersection area?

- Note that I am aware of convex polygon intersection and area algorithms; however, I do not necessarily need the actual intermediate intersection area polygon definition, only the final area value itself so I'm wondering if there are some efficiencies to be gained over this straightforward approach.
- Triangle-based approaches are fine too.
- Approximate approaches may be of interest.

Comment: You can rotate them so that one is axes-aligned.More than that, I don't see anything simpler than actual convex intersection techniques.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think there was too much hope, but you never know until you ask... *sigh*

Comment: You might begin by committing to a "collision detection" approach (to rule out cases where the rectangles have no overlap).  The case-logic for this will provide a framework of exits in which the area of any overlap can be found as easily as possible.   Some Questions at StackOverflow are relevant.

Comment: After some digging, the Maillot algorithm is of interest; it deals with the case for subject convex polygons and clip axes-aligned rectangles. It is faster than the general convex-convex intersection case.